# Numpy array of lil_matrix objects - is empty?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I wanted to ask if there is a clean way to check for empty elements in a numpy object array containing other arrays.
Before I used to do this which essentially checks the size of the object inside and works fine if `x` is a numpy array:

```
[True if np.size(x) == 0 else False for x in metrics]
```

This however does not work when `x` is a scipy sparse lil_matrix array, where size returns `0`.

Is there any nice way to check if `metrics[x] == []`? So if it has not been set to anything?

EDIT: To give an example

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
metrics = np.empty(5, dtype=object)
metrics[2] = np.zeros((3,3))
metrics[3] = lil_matrix(np.zeros((3,3),dtype=bool))
```

I want to know that 0,1,4 are empty and 2,3 are not

If I run the above command I get:

```
In [6]: [True if np.size(x) == 0 else False for x in metrics]
Out[6]: [False, False, False, True, False]
```

Which is not what I want. I want `[True, True, False, False, True]`

Comment: lil_matrix is sparse matrix representation, values other than non-zero will be set to zero. You can check if a row/colom of a lil_matrix is all zero or not.

Comment: I am not trying to check if the sparse matrix is zero. I am trying to check if there is any matrix at all in the numpy array position `x`.

Comment: Your method should do exactly that. If a row of your lil_matrix has only zeros in int, ``np.size`` will return zero. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Can you give an example of array to check?

Comment: Is `x` always an `lil` matrix?  Are you checking shape or number of nonzero values?

Comment: No it can be a numpy array or a lil_matrix

Comment: I added an edit to explain what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the solution. Apparently empty object arrays set elements to None. 
Then I can just do

```
In [11]: [True if x is None else False for x in metrics]
Out[11]: [True, True, False, False, True]
```

to get my result

Comment: Normally I wouldn't test the values of an `empty` array, but with this object dtype `is None` works. But keep a watch for changes in future numpy releases.

Comment: If you don't test them how can you delete them? I did all this essentially to just remove all empty elements from the np.array.

Comment: With normal dtypes (int, float, etc) `np.empty` just leaves the bytes that happen to be in the allocated memory block.  Thus values can be almost anything.  With `dtype=object`, the entries are pointers to objects, and apparently the default is to point to the unique `None` object.  Usually when people initialize an array with `empty` they intend to set ALL values themselves.

Comment: Why are you using a object array instead of a list?

Comment: I wonder if you were conflating `np.empty` with the empty list, `[]`.  They are not related.

Comment: @hpaulj I intend to set all the values but sometimes there is an exception in my file reading due to an error in the file and I need to leave that element of the np array empty. Also I fill the array in with joblib.Parallel so I cannot just handle the exception and put the next object into the empty slot.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if it will work with lil_matrix but you could use something like the any() function for numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([])
b = np.array([1,2])
c = np.array([b,b,a,b])
d = [not m.any() for m in b]
```

This will give you a list of True/False. then you need somethink like:

```
all(d)
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, look at my example in the edit

Comment: You can add a 'not' in the list inclusion. I've completed the answer

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'any'`
Any doesn't work on empty array elements. Look at my solution.

Comment: for NoneType it will not work indeed. But for the empty elements (if it is like a) it works. If the empty elements are something different from an empty numpy array then sure.

Comment: I think I understood now what you meant with empty. If you use the np.empy function you'll see that the values held may be different from 0. In that case I would advise to not use it